# condition where a <> ' ' and a <> '' not working

Tags: sql, oracle

I wrote a SQL to query table mat from an oracle db where column A is not null. Column A is varchar and its default value is ' '. I wrote the sql below:

```
select * from mat where matnr='test' and A <>'' and A <> ' '
```

But it return an empty data set.

Then I ran:

```
select * from mat where matnr='test' and A <> ' '
```

This query worked. So what is the reason? Thx.

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Comment: @ Bob Jarvis - Слава Україні oracle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, `''` means `NULL`. Any direct comparison to NULL returns NULL instead of TRUE or FALSE, so you cannot say `A <> ''` - you must say `A IS NOT NULL`.

Another possibility would be to use the `NVL` function, replacing `NULL` with `' '`, so that you could say

```
select * from mat where matnr='test' and NVL(A, ' ') <> ' '
```